# Using Field Calculator to assign consecutive letters for each feature?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, python-parser, vbscript, string

I have a feature class generated in ModelBuilder using a transect script that contains multiple transects.  Before moving on to further build the survey I would like to assign ID's to each feature in the class using field calculator.  It needs to be string, i.e. A,B,C....and so on.  After 26 features I would like to name it AA, BB, CC and so on.

Does anyone have a script that could accomplish this?

Comment: Have you written/found the code to do this using sequential numbers?  Once you have that this distills to a pure Python question that I think will be better researched at [so].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Field Calculator (with Python) - Check Show Codeblock on.

This will cycle through the alphabet A-Z, then AA-ZZ and then AAA - ZZZ and so on

Pre-Logic Script

```
import string
alphabet = list(string.ascii_uppercase)
record_count = 0
multiplier = 0

def alphabet_ID():
    global alphabet
    global record_count
    global multiplier
    if record_count % len(alphabet) == 0:
        multiplier += 1
        record_count += 1
        return alphabet[0] * multiplier
    else:
        alpha_index = record_count % len(alphabet)
        record_count += 1     
        return alphabet[alpha_index] * multiplier
```

Function block

```
alphabet_ID()
```